# How do I rearrange tags on my Developer Story page?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, developer-story

On my [developer story page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3357935), [travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci) is currently listed as the ***last*** tag under 'I want to work with'.

I want my experience with [travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci) to displayed prominently next to [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github), as the two skills compliment each other nicely and are fields I am very interested in.

**How can I rearrange tags on my developer story page?**

[image: "I want to work with" on developer story page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't drag-and-drop, but you can accomplish this with the keyboard:

1. Delete the `travis-ci` tag from your list
2. Use the keyboard arrows to navigate just after the github text
3. Type `,` on the keyboard and enter `travis-ci`